# Updating a form in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 models: User and Profile, for which I have created 2 form classes.

#### Forms

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['dob','country']

class UserForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','first_name','last_name','email','password']
```

#### My Profile Model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
      country = CountryField()
      dob = models.DateField(max_length=10)
      profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image',blank=True)
```

How do I save these forms?

`forms.save()` seems to be of no help.

#### View

```
def profile(request):
    print(request.user)
    form1 = UserForm()
    form2  = UserProfileForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            form1.save()
            form2.save()
    return render(request,'account/profile.html',{'form1':form1, 'form2':form2})
```

Comment: When I submit the form, it just calls the function and refreshes the page. When viewed through django admin it does not update the Models

Comment: Be sure you are using POST method in the template form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this because you not saving any data to the database:

```
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def profile(request):
    print(request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = UserForm(request.POST)
        form2  = UserProfileForm(request.POST)

        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            profile = Profile()
            user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)

            user.username = form1.cleaned_data['username']
            user.first_name = form1.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = form1.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.email = form1.cleaned_data['email']
            user.set_password(form1.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.save()

            profile.user = request.user # user field cannot be empty
            profile.dob = form2.cleaned_data['dob']
            profile.country = form2.cleaned_data['country']
            profile.save()
    else:
        form1 = UserForm()
        form2  = UserProfileForm() 

    context = {
       'form1' : form1,
       'form2' : form2
      }

    return render(request,'account/profile.html', context = context)
```

This is a correct way of doing it and checking if it is `GET` return empty form. But I am not sure if you will able to save profile and user at the same time since you have a foreign key in profile and it cannot be empty. You need to have a predefined users.

Comment: Thank you. Once the form is filled up, instead of passing the empty form how can how can i fill it with the data given by user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in data to the forms in order for validation to occur and upon successful validation, saving the model. Right now, `form1.is_valid()` and `form2.is_valid()` always return `False`, and you are not handling this case, so the page is just re-rendered.

```
def profile(request):
    print(request.user)
    form1 = forms.UserForm()
    form2 = forms.UserProfileForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = forms.UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form = forms.UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            form1.save()
            form2.save()
        else:
            return Http404 
    return render(request,'account/profile.html',{'form1':form1, 'form2':form2})
```